# MediaMetadataRetriever results in mostly null values

Tags: android

I'm trying to get mp3 tags from some music files

```
MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();

File filenm = new File(path, availableFiles[0]);
mmr.setDataSource(showFileActivity.this,Uri.fromFile(filenm));
String column = mmr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE):
```

I can get correct DURATION and BITRATE tags, so I know I'm setting the data source on the correct file, but everything else comes back null. The other tags, such as Album, are present, as I can pull the file from the device and verify they are there.

Is there a better way to get mp3 tags? Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: If the files are store on the device (which appears to be the case based on your example) you can always try retrieving the metadata by querying Android's MediaStore directly. Have you tried that?

Comment: no, went another route and used a 3rd party library - myID3